# error MinimumOSVersion, Invalid segment Alignment

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I got a problem today with Xcode 6.2(6C131e)
When i archive app to upload to store, it show 2 error:

- MinimumOSVersion in library import into project like
  Spring/Alamofire/SQLite
- Invalid Segment Alignment

Here some screenshot config of my app:

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBG5U.png]]

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRdO6.png]]

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/odMuw.png]]

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZszo.png]]

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QBJi.png]]

I have searching and do step by step some guide in stack but no help me solve this problem.
Thanks for investigate :)

Comment: you can add image to your post by click on the image icon in text tool

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to solve this problem by myself.

I want to share with another get this issued.

Turn out, this serial error because i use swift and add some framework just work in os 8.0 ( Alamofire/ Spring/ SQLite ). 
i'm fix this issued and let app still compatible with os 7.0 by :

- delete framework, and after that i import folder source of framework
  by hand.
- Edit in storyboard module of object use framework ( like    Spring)

And now my app work like charm and pass upload to store :)